# Implicit downcast from 'UnityEngine.Component[]' to 'UnityEngine.ParticleEmitter[]'

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
#pragma strict

static var charge : int = 0;
var collectSound : AudioClip;
//HUD
var hudCharge : Texture2D[];
var chargeHudGUI : GUITexture;
//Generator
var meterCharge : Texture[];
var meter : Renderer;
//Matches
private var haveMatches : boolean = false;
var matchGUIprefab : GUITexture;
private var matchGUI : GUITexture;
var fireEmitters : ParticleEmitter[];
var TextHints : GUIText;

function Start ()
{
    charge = 0;
}

function Update ()
{

}

function CellPickup()
{
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(collectSound, transform.position);
    charge++;
    chargeHudGUI.texture = hudCharge[charge];
    meter.material.mainTexture = meterCharge[charge];
    HUDon();
}

function HUDon()
{
    if(!chargeHudGUI.enabled)
    {
        chargeHudGUI.enabled = true;
    }
}

function MatchPickup()
{
    haveMatches = true;
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(collectSound, transform.position);
    var matchHUD : GUITexture = Instantiate(matchGUIprefab, Vector3(0.15,0.1,0),transform.rotation);
    matchGUI = matchHUD;
}

function OnControllerColliderHit(col : ControllerColliderHit)
{
    if(col.gameObject.name == "campfire")
    {
        if(haveMatches)
        {
            LightFire(col.gameObject);
        }

        else
        {
            TextHints.SendMessage("ShowHint", "i could use this campfire to signal for help... \n if only i could light it");
        }
    }
}

function LightFire(campfire : GameObject)
{
    fireEmitters = campfire.GetComponentsInChildren(ParticleEmitter);
    for(var emitter : ParticleEmitter in fireEmitters)
    {
        emitter.emit = true;
    }
    campfire.audio.Play();
    Destroy(matchGUI);
    haveMatches=false;
}
```

i was 1st having a problem saying can't cast from source type to destination type then i added pragma strict and now i'm getting the error in the title, now i'm writing more because the **lovely** website thinks that that didn't explain enough.

Comment: Note for future: don't bite the hand that feeds you

Comment: i Appreciate the upvote but would rather an answer more :P

Comment: Don't post the same thing in two places without crosslinks.http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/223836/invalid-cast-exception-array-of-particle-systems.html

Comment: i hardly have to do that when the sites aren't even connected

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not familiar with this apparently typed variant of javascript, but assuming it's something like the other Java-family languages and has C-style casts, I would try this in `LightFire`:

```
var emitters : Component[] = campfire.GetComponentsInChildren(ParticleEmitter);
for(var emitter : Component in fireEmitters)
{
    ((ParticleEmitter)emitter).emit = true;
}
```

If that's not the right syntax, then find out how to do a downcast.

Comment: sorry dude didn't work thanks though appreciate the effort i'll look up downcasting like you said

Comment: Any more information about the error message would be helpful.  What line?  Is it at compile time or run time?

Comment: the problem is at runtime and line 73

Comment: Huh.  It looks like `emitters` has some things in it which are not actually `ParticleEmitters`.  But I thought `GetComponentsInChildren` would filter that for you, since you gave it as an argument.  Perhaps not.  Do some debugging and see what type `emitter` is... or insert a check that it is a `ParticleEmitter` before setting the proprety -- however you do that in this language.

Comment: for whatever reason it seems to not be recognizing particleEmitter as a component and then it's complaining because there not the same type